# Why AppleScript can't implement JavaScript snippets?

Tags: javascript, syntax, applescript, syntax-error

I want to implement some JavaScript functions in an AppleScript. The problem is that everytime I use "do JavaScript" I get an error message saying "Expected end of line but found identifier!". What's wrong with the following simple script?

```
tell application "Safari" to open location "www.apple.com"
do javascript "alert('Hello World');"
end tell
```

This is a very simple example and I'm very sure that `do javascript` makes the problem.
Actually I wanted to make an AppleScript which clicks a button on a website. After that it deletes the cache and clicks on the button again. And I need JavaScript for the button click simulation. And the error warning is driving me crazy…

I tested that problem on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and 10.5.8…
If you don't have a solution for the problem I'd have another question: Which other programming/scripting language (Mac) do you recommend for solving my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem to do what you want when you tell Safari in which tab to run the script;

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "www.apple.com"
    do JavaScript "alert('Hello World');" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

EDIT: You added a new problem to the comments where the Javascript was a bit "off", here's a working version;

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "www.apple.com"
end tell

delay 0.5
set safe to false
repeat until safe
    delay 0.2
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1
        if result is "Complete" then exit repeat
    end tell
    tell application "Safari" to set PageText to the text of document 1
    if length of PageText is greater than 10000 then set safe to true
end repeat

tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('gn-iphone').children[0].click();" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

Comment: Thx dude! That works perfect! So `in current tab of first window` was the missing part?

Comment: Yes, I'm also not sure how `to` interacts with multi line tells, so I put `open` along side `do` to make it clear that both rows belong to the same `tell`.

Comment: OK thx! Do you coincidentally also know why this isn't working?

`tell application "Safari"
    open location "www.apple.com"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByID('gn-iphone').click();" in current tab of first window
 
end tell`

I want the code to open `apple.com` and then click at the menu on `iPhone`… The source code of `apple.com` says the ID of that menu button is `gn-iphone`. So what's the mistake?

Comment: @Retador I suspect your Javascript loads before the page is fully loaded. [This link](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=35176) may help.

Comment: Thx dude! You were VERY helpful! Sorry, I don't have enough reputation for voting your answers up…